# How would I select a value of a string that is in parentheses?

Tags: javascript

I want to select the contents of the second pair of parentheses in this string

> "Hello my name is (john) (doe)."

How would I go about doing that? In addition, if there were an unknown number of pairs of parentheses, how would I be able to select the contents of the last one?

Comment: Have you considered using regex?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of possibilities. The first uses a regex to grab text between the last pair of parentheses (asserted using a lookahead that asserts there are no more opening parentheses after the last closing one), the second uses `split`, first on an opening parenthesis, grabbing the last value and then splitting that on a closing parenthesis and taking the first part of the result:

```js
const str = "Hello my name is (john) (doe)."

result = str.match(/(?<=\()[^)]*(?=\)[^(]*$)/)[0]
console.log(result)

result = str.split('(').pop().split(')')[0]
console.log(result)
```